# Matplotlib.pyplot: global name time is not defined error

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I recently started experiencing a strange problem with pyplot in my jupyter notebook. when trying to `pyplot.pause()`, I get a name error in the actual matplotlib package.

This name error does not occur in the exact same code executed as a `.py` file rather than an `.ipynb`. Everything else executes the same between the `.py` and `.ipynb`, and they both use the same virtualenvironment and packages.

## Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------
NameError          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-11e7508f518d> in <module>()
     32         plt.title('Epoch: {0}, loss: {1:.4}'.format(epoch, loss_history[epoch-1]))
     33         plt.show()
---> 34         plt.pause(0.001)
     35         #display.display(plt.gcf())
     36         #display.display(plt.show())
/home/user/.pyenv/versions/2.7.14/envs/P2714/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in pause(interval)
    292         canvas.start_event_loop(interval)
    293     else:
--> 294         time.sleep(interval)
    295 
    296 
NameError: global name 'time' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug report about this issue reported [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9412). The issue is a missing `import time`statement in pyplot.py.

[A pull request](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/9415) solving this issue has already been merged into the master branch and should be included in version 2.1.1.

I can confirm that by using pyplot.py from the matplotlib master branch this problem does not appear for me anymore.

Comment: @Alnitak, it only uses time.sleep when there is no figure, e.g. after the figure has been destroyed when the program is closing. Presumably something about running in a notebook (choice of backend?) causes _pylab_helpers.Gcf.get_active() to return None. Makes me wonder if pyplot.pause is really working as you think it is;
 it's probably just calling time.sleep. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/1493192430c9fe8d5d998352dd6f71168c2de317/lib/matplotlib/pyplot.py#L294